# heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 when deploying keystonejs-demo

Tags: heroku, keystonejs

I deploy keystonejs-demo to heroku. It says successfully deplayed, but throws errors when I try to run the application:

```
2019-04-23T16:17:45.643784+00:00 app[web.1]:    'failed to connect to server [mongo-cluster-ixqtu.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-cluster-ixqtu.mongodb.net mongo-cluster-ixqtu.mongodb.net:27017]' }

2019-04-23T16:17:45.645113+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: KeystoneJS (Keystone Demo) failed to start - Check that you are running `mongod` in a separate process.
2019-04-23T16:17:45.645116+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js:62:10)
2019-04-23T16:17:45.645117+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:189:13)
2019-04-23T16:17:45.645119+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:17
2019-04-23T16:17:45.645120+00:00 app[web.1]:     at connectCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:527:5)
2019-04-23T16:17:45.645121+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:418:11
2019-04-23T16:17:45.645123+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
2019-04-23T16:18:17.397825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=keystone-md2.herokuapp.com request_id=d7ff1bf6-735a-4312-96e6-6ec889a154eb fwd="193.238.220.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-23T16:18:18.027043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=keystone-md2.herokuapp.com request_id=0a56b395-e71d-4162-bb21-18e265b31fd8 fwd="193.238.220.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

connection code:

```
'mongo': process.env.MONGO_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/keystone-demo',
```

Comment: It looks like your MongoDB connection isn't working. Please [edit] your question and show your connection code. Make sure to redact sensitive information.

Comment: @Chris please take a look, I added connection code..

Comment: Before you do anything else, please reset those credentials. You haven't hidden them very well and you shouldn't rely on them anymore. Now, that image doesn't show your connection code. It just shows your `MONGO_URI` environment variable. Where do you _use_ that in your code? Please [edit] your question and paste the relevant code into it. You can format it as code by selecting it and clicking the {} button or pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: @Chris is it right this time? this line is from keystone.js